# Is there a better way to write the following method in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a small program, in python, which will find a lone missing element from an arithmetic progression (where the starting element could be both positive and negative and the series could be ascending or descending).

so for example: if the input is 1 3 5 9 11, then the function should return 7 as this is the lone missing element in the above AP series. 
The input format: the input elements are separated by 1 white space and not commas as is commonly done.

Here is the code:

```
def find_missing_elm_ap_series(n, series):
    ap = series
    ap = ap.split(' ')
    ap = [int(i) for i in ap]
    cd = []
    for i in range(n-1):
        cd.append(ap[i+1]-ap[i])
    common_diff = 0

    if len(set(cd)) == 1:
        print 'The series is complete'
        return series
    else:
        cd = [abs(i) for i in cd]
        common_diff = min(cd)
        if ap[0] > ap[1]:
            common_diff = (-1)*common_diff


    new_ap = []
    for i in range(n+1):
        new_ap.append(ap[0] + i*common_diff)

    missing_element = set(new_ap).difference(set(ap)) 
    return missing_element
```

where n is the length of the series provided (the series with the missing element:5 in the above example).

I am sure there are other shorter and more elegant way of writing this code in python. Can anybody help ? 
Thanks
BTW: i am learning python by myself and hence the question.

Comment: I think this is a question better suited to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), given this is about improving code that is already working.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about it.

Comment: Also, thanks to everybody who left their thoughts and solutions of my question. In each of the codes below, I learned something new. My aim is to write elegant code and not just something that will do the job. So thanks all of you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the fact that if an element is missing it is exactly `expected-sum(series) - actual-sum(series)`. The expected sum for a series with `n` elements starting at `a` and ending at `b` is `(a+b)*n/2`. The rest is Python:

```
def find_missing(series):
    A = map(int, series.split(' '))
    a, b, n, sumA = A[0], A[-1], len(A), sum(A)

    if (a+b)*n/2 == sumA:
        return None #no element missing

    return (a+b)*(n+1)/2-sumA

print find_missing("1 3 5 9")    #7
print find_missing("-1 1 3 5 9") #7
print find_missing("9 6 0")      #3
print find_missing("1 2 3")      #None
print find_missing("-3 1 3 5")   #-1
```

Comment: Thanks @Juan Lopes. I should have seen that. But the fact is, I didn't and thanks a lot. Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well... You can do simpler, but it would completely change your algorithm.

First, you can prove that the step for the arithmetic progression is `ap[1] - ap[0]`, unless `ap[2] - ap[1]` is lower in magnitude than it, in which case the missing element is between terms 0 and 1. (This is true as there is a single missing element.)

Then you can just take `ap[0] + n * step` and print the first one that doesn't match.

Here is the source code (also implementing some minor shortcuts, such as grouping your first three lines into one):

```
def find_missing_elm_ap_series(n, series):
    ap = [int(i) for i in series.split(' ')]
    step = ap[1] - ap[0]
    if (abs(ap[2] - ap[1]) <= abs(step)): # Check missing elt is not between 0 and 1
        return ap[0] + ap[2] - ap[1]
    for (i, val) in zip(range(len(ap)), ap): # And check position of missing element
        if ap[0] + i * step != val:
            return ap[0] + i * step
    return series # missing element not found
```

Answer (score 1):

The code appears to be working. There is perhaps a slightly easier way to get it done. This is due to the fact that you don't have to attempt to look through all of the values to get the common difference. The following code simply looks at the difference between the 1st and 2nd as well as the last and second last.

This works in the event that only a single value is missing (and the length of the list is at least 3). As the min difference between the values will provide you the common difference.

```
def find_missing(prog):
    # First we cast them to numbers.
    items = [int(x) for x in prog.split()]

    #Then we compare the first and second
    first_to_second =  items[1] - items[0]

    #then we compare the last to second last
    last_to_second_last = items[-1] - items[-2]

    #Now we have to care about which one is closes
    # to zero
    if abs(first_to_second) < abs(last_to_second_last):
        change = first_to_second
    else:
        change = last_to_second_last


    #Iterate through the list. As soon as we find a gap
    #that is larger than change, we fill in and return

    for i in range(1, len(items)):
        comp = items[i] - items[i-1]

        if comp != change:
            return items[i-1] + change

    #There was no gap
    return None

print(find_missing("1 3 5 9"))    #7
print(find_missing("-1 1 3 5 9")) #7
print(find_missing("9 6 0"))      #3
print(find_missing("1 2 3"))      #None
```

The previous code shows this example. First of all attempting to find change between each of the values of the list. Then iterating till the change is missed, and returning the value that has been expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I thought about it: find the position of the maximum difference between the elements of the array; then regenerate the expected number in the sequence from the other differences (which should be all the same and the minimum number in the differences list):

```
def find_missing(a):
    d = [a[i+1] - a[i] for i in range(len(a)-1)]
    i = d.index(max(d))
    x = min(d)
    return a[0] + (i+1)*x

print find_missing([1,3,5,9,11])
7
print find_missing([1,5,7,9,11])
3
```

Comment: Nice short solution, but will be slow on (really) big sets. Also needs to handle negative difference progressions.

Comment: You're right, of course. It would be easy to fix the algorithm to cope with negative differences (swap `max` and `min`), but there's no getting around the fact that this will be slow for huge sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first & last items are not missing, we can also make use of `range()` or `xrange()` with the **step** of the common difference, getting rid of the `n` altogether, it can also return more than 1 missing item (although not reliably depending on number of items missing):

```
In [13]: def find_missing_elm(series):
             ap = map(int, series.split())
             cd = map(lambda x: x[1]-x[0], zip(ap[:-1], ap[1:]))
             if len(set(cd)) == 1:
                 print 'complete series'
                 return ap
             mcd = min(cd) if ap[0] < ap[1] else max(cd)
             sap = set(ap)
             return filter(lambda x: x not in sap, xrange(ap[0], ap[-1], mcd))
   ....:

In [14]: find_missing_elm('1 3 5 9 11 15')
Out[14]: [7, 13]

In [15]: find_missing_elm('15 11 9 5 3 1')
Out[15]: [13, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas:

- Passing the length of the series seems like a bad idea.  The function can more easily calculate the length
- There is no reason to assign series to ap, just do a function using series and assign the result to ap
- When splitting the string, don't give the sep argument.  If you don't give the argument, then consecutive white space will also be removed and leading and trailing white space will also be ignored.  This is more friendly on the format of the data.
- I've combined a few operations.  For example the split and the list comprehension converting to integer make sense to group together.  There is also no need to create cd as a list and then convert that to a set.  Just build it as a set to start with.
- I don't like that the function returns the original series in the case of no missing element.  The value None would be more in keeping with the name of the function.
- Your original function returned a one item set as the result.  That seems odd, so I've used pop() to extract that item and return just the missing element.
- The last item was more of an experiment with combining all of the code at the bottom into a single statement.  Don't know if it is better, but it's something to think about.  I built a set with all the correct numbers and a set with the given numbers and then subtracted them and returned the number that was missing.

Here's the code that I came up with:

```
def find_missing_elm_ap_series(series):
    ap = [int(i) for i in series.split()]
    n = len(ap)
    cd = {ap[i+1]-ap[i] for i in range(n-1)}

    if len(cd) == 1:
        print 'The series is complete'
        return None
    else:
        common_diff = min([abs(i) for i in cd])
        if ap[0] > ap[1]:
            common_diff = (-1)*common_diff

    return set(range(ap[0],ap[0]+common_diff*n,common_diff)).difference(set(ap)).pop()
```

Comment: Thanks @Brad Budlong for your thoughts. Your points are spot on. I learned a lot. Thanks